# Faster grayscale to color hover for large photoset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have about 2000 images with a greyscale filter. When I remove the grayscale filter the opacity hover effects is almost instantaneous. However, with the grayscale, it's quite slow.

I was wondering if there was a better method at achieving this effect that would be better for the user experience speed of the hover.

```
.image { 
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.2;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%); 
    filter: gray;
}
.image:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;  
}
```

[Demo with Grayscale](https://codepen.io/bgold/pen/JJNWzB?editors=1100) (notice how it is much slower then below)

[Demo **without** Grayscale](https://codepen.io/bgold/pen/VWbpJR?editors=1100) (notice how it is quite fast)

[Video showing slowness](https://streamable.com/ks2or)

Comment: Have you tried setting a transition value?

Comment: Post a code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LGSon updated question with demo

Comment: I saw... just tried it and on my computer I can't see any difference -- using Intel Core m3-6Y30 0.90GHz 1.51GHz - 4GB RAM - Win 10 Pro, which is not a rocket :)

Comment: Hmm, I have a way more powerful computer and I can see a pretty noticeable different between when the mouse hits an image and the image changes to color. I'll make a video @LGSon

Comment: Ok .. and which browser do you use?

Comment: @LGSon safari on Mac. Updated question with video let me know what you think

Comment: @bryan safari ok let me test

Comment: @LGSon it is related to `filter` on safari, it is very slow. @bryan yes you are right it is very slow on safari.

Comment: @DanielH indeed, not too bad on Chrome

Comment: @bryan check this on safari, should fixed now. https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/gRWWEm?editors=1100

Comment: @bryan turns out if you move the `filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */` up to top it is much faster, I don't know why...

Comment: @DanielH You. are. the. man! Please update your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @bryan I have to research why this happened. for now, I really don't know why lol. I will update my research later ~.~ lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP's codepen, turns out if you move the `filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */` and `filter: none; /* IE 6-9 */` up it is so much faster in Safari, not sure why this is happening I will research and update later, for now, this is the solution for safari slowness on `filter`

```
section#pitches > div {
  width: 6.25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
section#pitches > div > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%); /* Firefox 4+ */
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
section#pitches > div > div:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: none; /* IE 6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

#### LINK to code pen: https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/gRWWEm?editors=1100

Seems like the order does matters, I have found few post talk about the slowness (300-500ms delay) on safari that never been resolved for many years with `filter` at the end of other browsers specific filter. But from this post, all the code are ordered as filter then browser specific rule. Seems a solution

#### I hope someone seen this could give a solid explanation of what happened?

> REF: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/
>
> [image]

Comment: @LGSon by default it should be 0s, (maybe OP have inherit it from parent's CSS?) adding transition and set it could overwrite and might fix it?

Comment: @LGSon Cool, this is not an answer. I will remove it.

Comment: It's specifically the grayscale that is causing the problem. The transition makes it seem more *laggy*. I will get a demo up

Comment: @bryan Cool, a demo will be great

Comment: @bryan my example I have 400 images

Comment: I updated my question with a Demo. It's more like 2000 images. So I'm just trying to find an appropriate solution. If there is none, then it's back to the drawing board haha

Comment: @DanielH check out the video in my updated question. It's a pretty big difference on my end and I have 16GB of ram.

Comment: @LGSon Updated with 400 different images size up to 400x2400

Comment: @bryan ok check my updated code, do you see a delay there? Just want to make sure it is code or just environment

Comment: @DanielH in full screen there is a delay. Within the answer, there isn't.